# Using Index Match within a non-standard table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, dashboard

I have a daily performance manager for Google Ads and the like. Each day or every few days I copy basic metric data into the table and I can see performance and budget spend over time.

It looks something like this:

```
date        Clicks Impression CTR   Cost Conversions CPA   CPC   CVR
01/03/2019  23       150      15%    $20   2         $10  $0.67  8.7%
02/03/2019  23       150      15%    $20   2         $10  $0.67  8.7%
03/03/2019  23       150      15%    $20   2         $10  $0.67  8.7%
04/03/2019  23       150      15%    $20   2         $10  $0.67  8.7%
05/03/2019  23       150      15%    $20   2         $10  $0.67  8.7%
06/03/2019  23       150      15%    $20   2         $10  $0.67  8.7%
07/03/2019  23       150      15%    $20   2         $10  $0.67  8.7%
08/03/2019  23       150      15%    $20   2         $10  $0.67  8.7%
09/03/2019  23       150      15%    $20   2         $10  $0.67  8.7%
```

An so on until the end of the month. This repeats for each month. At the end of each Month section it has the name of the month and the totals for each month.

I manage a lot of clients and I've made one Excel Workbook that allows me to do this all with a sheet for each client. My issue is that I would like a dashboard that has a snapshot of each client's performance across the month to make it easier for myself.

My first attempt was using **INDEX MATCH**, however, you need a table for it to work. So I attempted to use named ranges to create the table. I created a *Client1StatsTable* where I selected just the rows with the month totals and a *Client1MonthName* range which had the month name.

This meant that I thought I could run the range in an **INDEX MATCH** as if it were a real table. I wrote the following 2 formulas:

```
INDEX(Client1StatsTable, MATCH(TEXT(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()),DAY(TODAY())),"mmmm"),Client1MonthName,0), 3)  
INDEX(Client1StatsTable,MATCH(K12,Client1MonthName,0),3)
```

I would repeat this for each client to get a month-to-date snapshot of the performance across the different metrics.

However, I got the *#N/A* error. When I ran it through the *Evaluate Formula* function in Excel I found that even though the range was parsed correctly as multiple rows and cells that were disconnected, it got stuck when it tried to place the *Month* in *MATCH*.

It parsed the month correctly, but just couldn't find it in the range.

The end table should have every client in one table and look like:

```
Date     ClientName    CTR  CPC  CPA  CVR  Spend  Amount of Budget Used
04/03/2019  Client 1    5%   $0.86  $15  2%   $30   15%
```

I would preferably like to accomplish this without using VBA.

Comment: Have you considered using pivot tables?

Comment: Pivot table would only theoretically work for Year-to-Date snapshot that's represented by the 2nd formula. Because in that case I would have to create a separate table for each client. For the month-to-date, I'm looking to create a snapshot for the current month for each client in one table. It would like something like:  

    **Date     Client Name    CTR    CPC    CPA     CVR   Spend    Amount of Budget Used**

Comment: INDEX and MATCH don't need the data to be in a table: the indexed range can be on sheet 2 and the match range on sheet 1, **all** that is needed is for both ranges to be the same length.

Comment: Both formulas worked for me. I did have to change the date formatting to "MMMM" though since "mmmm" was minutes instead of months (this may be system-language dependent). You may also want to look into PowerQuery (add-in for 2010/2013, integrated in 2016) for this if you haven't already.

Comment: @SolarMike yes, but based on _Evaluate Formula_ tool. It gets stuck within MATCH By itself

Comment: @hsan can you please replicate your working. It has not worked for me and the "mmmm" does translate into the correct full month name for me. It just can't find that month in the Range provided, even though it is there.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't any whitespace (or "invisible") characters around the month name? Does the formula `=Client1MonthName="March"` result in `TRUE` or `FALSE`? Also, your first formula uses `Client1MonthName` the second `ClientMonthName` without the "1".

Comment: @hsan thanks I corrected that. Should have had a 1 in it. Also, Client1MonthName doesn't have a singular value. It's a range that includes the name of month as it appears at the bottom of each month section as a total row

Comment: Still works if I change the named range to the whole row. Did you check that the name of the month in that row is equal to the value you get from the date formula? Should show true in a simple comparison.

Comment: @hsan yes it's fine. I even changed the named range from just selecting the relevant rows to all the rows and it worked with MATCH but not with Index as it had a #REF error. Please note, that the rows are not adjacent to each other

Comment: I think I begin to understand what you are doing. A sample file or more complete data sample would have really helped speed this up... Both named ranges are non-contiguous, correct (e.g. month name: A10,A20,A30,...)? Then I am afraid `MATCH` will just not work. But I don't see why you couldn't just use the whole column instead. Like this: `INDEX(C:C,MATCH(K12,A:A,0),1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I found the answer, thanks to @hsan, I had initially thought that the values in between the names of the individual months would get in the way of the **INDEX MATCH**. I looked back at the original code that tested it and I had set the final value in MATCH to -1. 
So it was:

```
INDEX(ClientName1!$A$42:$K$420,MATCH(TEXT(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()),DAY(TODAY())),"mmmm"),ClientName1!$A$42:$A$420,-1),3)
```

But when I did

```
INDEX(ClientName1!$A$42:$K$420,MATCH(TEXT(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()),DAY(TODAY())),"mmmm"),ClientName1!$A$42:$A$420,0),3)
```

it worked

Answer (score 0):

You can recreate a `pivot table` to your convienience using `sumproduct-filters` with `booleans`

```
=Sumproduct(--(condition_1);--(condition_2); Sum_of_range)
```

Here's with your example:

**CTR for client A at date 4/3/19**

```
= Sumproduct(--(Client_range='A');--(Date_range='4/3/19'); Sum_of_CTR)
```

[image]

Do the same for the rest of the fields of your dashboard

Comment: Each client has their own sheet and there is a tally already at the bottom of each month section for each sheet. I am trying to build a table on a dashboard that pulls in that total for Month-to-Date, in a way that dynamically selects the appropriate month.